# Match point to polygons in a big polygon list

Tags: java, algorithm, gis, polygon

I have a big list of polygons (say size 250,000) and a big list of points (say size 100,000). What I need to do is to find to which polygon(s) does each of these points belong.

The polygons are always rectangles/diamonds with 5 points where first and last point are the same. They also have its approximate center point associated to polygon.
An example polygon is as follows: Polygon(a;b;c;d;a) = (3,1; 5,3; 3,5; 1,3; 3,1) and Center Point (x) = (3, 3). See sample figure below:

```
          c (3,5)
         /\
        /  \
(1,3) d/    \b (5,3)
       \ x  /
        \  /
         \/
          a (3,1)
```

This is a simplified example. Most of these points are lat-lon/GIS coordinates.

The input list of points may not match to any polygons or may match to one or more of the polygons in the polygons list.

Currently I have a function that takes a point and a polygon to see if the point is inside polygon or not. Anytime I want to see a point is in the polygon, I have to iterate through the complete list of polygons to see if it match or not. Also as a point may be in more than one polygon, I have to iterate through the complete list every time. This is very inefficient.

What I'm looking for is some ordering of these polygons into a HashMap or something so that I can quickly fetch a few polygons that need to be checked for each point instead of complete list of polygons. As the points has both x and y params, I'm not able to find a good way to order the polygons.
Also note that every polygon has a center point. So is there a way to order the polygons based on these center points as key so that we can easily lookup?

Any thoughts/ideas on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a k-d tree, which is an efficient partitioning of space

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Answer (score 0):

Split your 2D space into square cells, for each cell store list of polygons that intersect with the cell.  When you need to check point, first find the cell point belongs to, then iterate through all polygons that intersect with this cell and test.  Choose cell size so there will be reasonable number of polygons per cell.

If your polygons distribution is uneven, you may want to use [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) instead of square cells.